# Date not showing in SSRS table

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I am working in SQL Server 2008  R2 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.  I have a view of a table that displays current work in house.  The table is grouped by customer and then by Activity number.  I am showing data with dates of each stage.  In the original table the field is defined as Date.  And when I query the database directly, the expected value is displayed.  I have this dataset configured in visual studio that queries the view.  When I execute the query inside of visual studio, I see the values in the fields I believe they should be.  When I include them in the report, nothing shows up.  I have tried to format the text box within the table to show a date, removed all formatting, formatting the field using the fx button.  I can honestly say I am confused as to why I am having such a difficult time with this one.[image: Field in question - ImportDate]

Here is the report 
[image: Field is called out on the report]

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it show expected values when query is executed in query designer in visual studio ??

Comment: Yes that is the very strange part of this.  When I run the query from the data set, I get a value.  It is just not showing in the table.  I have also tried to use indicators and have tried =iif(isnothing(Fields!ImportDate.Value),1,0) and then made my indicator be Red if = 1 and Green if = 0 and that wouldn't work either.  So it seems like it is reading a null value regardless of what is in the database.

Comment: 1st try taking away all the formatting from that cell/column , if this doesnt work delete the column add it again, if this doesnt work delete the dataset and recreate it, I have seen some really really strange issues with SSRS. even though it is full of bugs but cant help not loving it for the things it can do for us :)

Comment: Make sure the dataset only has the one select statement, not the other lines in the screenshot. Also make sure SSRS is using the same database in the data sources.